# create video header when using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap building a web page
the template i am using: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/ 
my problem is I would like to change the header with a big image to a video 
(a example here: http://riskeverything.us/) 
firstly I thought that I just need to throw something like `<video></<video> tag` into the `<div></div>` block, and the `css` and `js` of bootstrap will do the rest, but it failed! 
**part of code been modified:**
```

```
<header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="intro-video">
        <video id="video" preload autoplay loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0"> 
            <source src="./one.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
            Video not supported
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="intro-text">
        <div class="intro-lead-in">Welcome To Our Studio!</div>
        <div class="intro-heading">It's Nice To Meet You</div>
        <a href="#services" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Tell Me More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
could some one tell me what further work should do, 
thanks!

Comment: thanks for modifying, @JqueryKing !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've right - simply `<video></video>` element with some CSS should works: http://take.ms/RWHMi

But what more important is that You need your video in specific formats http://take.ms/AuK1p

And here You have working example http://jsfiddle.net/h8rrhoua/

Also You can stop playing movie with code:

`window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    document.querySelector("#video").pause();
});`

IMHO Bootstrap is unnecessary for this job

Comment: hi, @Michal Kutra
the video could success playing on page,
I would like the video stop while I scroll down the page, does it could only be worked by using jQuery? or I could make it by only css

Comment: You can do it with poor Javascript. I've updated my answer. Take a look

Comment: @MichalKurta I had successfully showing video header and overlay some text or button on it.  
(http://jsfiddle.net/JasperCK/1uy2e8gq)  
thanks for the hint of using addEventlistener (just can't member this in mind at the time!!)  
further I had question, which I need to re-play the video while scroll back to upper of page, I'm not sure that could I use **SrollSpy** to achieve the goal? please give me some advice, thanks!!!

Comment: ScrollSpy from Bootstrap is rather to spying position of window to update menu classes. I think You need simply $(window).offset().top for checking if current position is grather than 0 (then video.pause() ) or else if is equal to 0 (then.play() )